Adjoint action in GA(3,1) : $v' = (exp -u) v exp u$, where u is an arbitray multivector of GA(3,1)
A general multivector of GA(3,1) can be expressed as $u=a+x+f+v+b$, where a is a scalar, x a vecotr, f a bivector, v a pseudo-vector and b a pseudo-scalar.
First, I am trying to understand what each adjoint action do

Dilations:
$$
w' = e^a w e^a
$$

Translations:
$$
w' = e^{-x} w e^x
$$

Lorentz SO(3,1) transformations
$$
w'=e^{-f} w e^f
$$

Unknown
$$
w' = e^{-v} w e^{v}
$$

Unknown (phase?)
$$
w'=e^{-b} w e^{b}
$$


where w is a vector of GA(3,1). What are the "unknown transformations"? What do they corresponds to?
I understand that exp u maps to the GL$^+$(4,R) group. How does the adjoint action as shown compare to multiply GL$^+$(4,R) with a vector. I understand the later generates a frame field.
I was also wondering if in general $e_\mu = e^{-u} \gamma_\mu e^u$ generates an arbitrary frame field? The reason for my hesitation that that by Translations we can already establish that the adjoint action can do a lot more than the GL$^+$(4,R) group. So maybe they are not equivalent?

These operations are not guaranteed to map vectors to vectors except in the case of bivector and scalar exponentials. Assuming $e_0^2 = -1$ and $e_1^2=e_2^2=e_3^2=1$ with all these forming an orthogonal basis, consider $$e^{\pi/4 e_0} = \frac1{\sqrt2}(1+e_0),$$$$\frac12(1-e_0)e_1(1+e_0) = \frac12e_1(1+e_0)^2=e_1e_0,$$ which is not a vector. I don't know why you think you're capable of representing translations like this either; in fact, it's impossible because what you've written is a linear transformation but translations are not linear.
